# Is there anyway to reduce the number of variables in this?

Tags: javascript, variables

I figured out an equation for finding digits of pi, and it seems to work fine with the for loop, but I was wondering if there was a way to reduce the 12 variables. The point of them is to increase the accuracy of the approximation, but there is a lot of them. I need a way to still have the functionality of the twelve variables, but written with less code.

Here is the full code:

```
function approximatePi() {
//Get P element
  var t = document.getElementById("t")
 //For loop
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
 //Variable for number close to pi//
    var a = 3.14
 //Math
    var a2 = a + Math.sin(a)
    var a3 = a2 + Math.sin(a2)
    var a4 = a3 + Math.sin(a3)
    var a5 = a4 + Math.sin(a4)
    var a6 = a5 + Math.sin(a5)
    var a7 = a6 + Math.sin(a6)
    var a8 = a7 + Math.sin(a7)
    var a9 = a8 + Math.sin(a8)
    var a10 = a9 + Math.sin(a9)
    var a11 = a10 + Math.sin(a10)
    var a12 = a11 + Math.sin(a11)
    var a13 = a12 + Math.sin(a12)
    var a14 = a13 + Math.sin(a13)
    var a15 = a14 + Math.sin(a14)
    t.innerText = parseFloat(a12).toPrecision(50)
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace the block with the lines `var a2 = a + Math.sin(a)` with `for (let i = 0; i < 12; ++i) a = a + Math.sin(a);`.

Answer (score 3):

You are repeating the same operation multiple times and printing the result after 12 steps. That can be simplified with a loop:

```
function approximatePi() {
//Get P element
  var t = document.getElementById("t")
 //For loop
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
 //Variable for number close to pi//
    var a = 3.14
 //Math
    for (let j = 0; j < 12; ++j) a = a + Math.sin(a);
    t.innerText = parseFloat(a).toPrecision(50)
  }
}
```

If you need all the results, use an array:

```
function approximatePi() {
//Get P element
  var t = document.getElementById("t")
 //For loop
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
 //Variable for number close to pi//
    var a = [3.14]
 //Math
    for (let j = 1; j <= 12; ++j) a[j] = a[j-1] + Math.sin(a[i-1]);
    t.innerText = parseFloat(a[12]).toPrecision(50)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work. Although, I am not 100 percent sure what the question is asking for. Could you type the question.

```
function approximatePi(){
var t = document.getElementById("t");
var a =[];
a[0] = 3.14;
    for(var i = 1; i<1000; i++){
         a[i] = a[i-1] + Math.sin(a[i-1]);
         

    }
    console.log(a[1]);
}
approximatePi();
```

Comment: Basically I wanted to keep the functionality of all the variables, while having it in a smaller amount of code. I figured it out though.